# Overtime column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Office times: 10:00 am to 18:00 pm.

I have wrote this query to display overtime if person has worked more than '8 hours', e.g. if he has worked '08:44 hours' than overtime shows 00:44 but now i don't want this.

I don't want to calculate it on the basis of `TOTAL WORK TIME`. I want if person has worked above than clock time 18:00 pm then that overtime should be shown.

e.g. if person has worked from 10:50 am to 18:33 pm than overtime column should show 00:33. Only if a person has worked above 18:00 pm, then the overtime should be caluclated.

n.b. Actually, our office policy is to pay employees stipend for overtime so they calculate overtime only above than 18:00 pm clock time, even if person arrives at office at 17:00 pm and has worked upto 18:54 pm even then he would be paid for 54mins overtime, apart from it the time he hasn't worked would result in deducation from pay but still applicable for overtime stipend.

```
WITH Times AS
(   SELECT  emp.EmplID, 
            emp.EmplName,
            InTime = MIN(atd.RecTime),
            OutTime = MAX(atd.RecTime),
            TimeWorked = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(atd.RecTime), MAX(atd.RecTime)),
            OverTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(atd.RecTime), MAX(atd.RecTime)) - 480,
            [DateVisited] = atd.RecDate
    FROM    AtdRecord atd 
            INNER JOIN HrEmployee emp 
                ON atd.EmplID = emp.EmplID 
    GROUP BY emp.EmplID, emp.EmplName, atd.RecDate
    HAVING COUNT(atd.RecTime) > 1
)
SELECT  t.EmplID,
        t.EmplName,
        t.InTime,
        t.OutTime,
        t.DateVisited,    
        TimeWorked = CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, t.TimeWorked, 0), 8),
        OverTime = CASE WHEN t.OverTime < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END +
                                CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, ABS(t.OverTime), 0), 8)
FROM Times t
```

Comment: removed caps and bold font as didn't add to the clarity of the question and is usually considered to be shouting/bad netiquette.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the logic you are trying for?

```
DECLARE @EndTimeA   TIME = '18:00',
        @EndTimeB   TIME = '18:05',
        @EndTimeC   TIME = '19:00',
        @EndTimeD   TIME = '17:55'


SELECT   OvertimeMM_A   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeA > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeA)
                                ELSE 0
                            END
        ,OvertimeMM_B   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeB > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeB)
                                ELSE 0
                            END
        ,OvertimeMM_C   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeC > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeC)
                                ELSE 0
                            END
        ,OvertimeMM_D   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeD > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeD)
                                ELSE 0
                            END
```

Expressed as `TIME`;

```
DECLARE @EndTimeA   TIME = '18:00',
        @EndTimeB   TIME = '18:05',
        @EndTimeC   TIME = '19:00',
        @EndTimeD   TIME = '17:55'


SELECT   CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, OvertimeMM_A, '00:00'), 8)
        ,CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, OvertimeMM_B, '00:00'), 8)
        ,CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, OvertimeMM_C, '00:00'), 8)
        ,CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, OvertimeMM_D, '00:00'), 8)
FROM 
(
    SELECT   OvertimeMM_A   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeA > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeA)
                                    ELSE 0
                                END
            ,OvertimeMM_B   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeB > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeB)
                                    ELSE 0
                                END
            ,OvertimeMM_C   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeC > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeC)
                                    ELSE 0
                                END
            ,OvertimeMM_D   =   CASE    WHEN @EndTimeD > '18:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '18:00', @EndTimeD)
                                    ELSE 0
                                END
)DT
```

Comment: See what ever time a person enters office, thats another story, what i want is that if person works above than 18:00pm then that time should be shown in overtime column, otherwise not,

Comment: Could you perhaps help me by explaining how the supplied code fails to perform the logic you just described?

Comment: Sok lemme test these but just tell me that wt is diff btw these two queries ? Do i have to run both

Comment: I think you would learn more by running them both and understand what they are doing. Because the logic you're asking for is described in the code.